# Pandas dataframe: work with nested different objects and not string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column object in Pandas like this:

```
{'totalSheets': 393, '_id': '59e52591265adce80, 'totalViews': 3640,}
{'totalSheets': 394, '_id': '59e6763a265adce80, 'totalViews': 3642,}
```

When I tried to split in str

```
df_split = df['column'].str.split(',',1)
print(df_split)
```

I have this output

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
```

The desired output could be

```
      totalSheets             _id                       totalViews 
1       393                59e52591265adce80              3640
2       394                59e6763a265adce80              3642
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Is this dict in columns ?

Comment: Hi @Wen-Ben thanks for the quick reply, it came from a Json file that I converted in a python string and then in a dataframe with pandas

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Thanks a lot to point this out @Wen-Ben I added in the description now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
pd.DataFrame(df['column'].tolist())
Out[354]: 
                 _id  totalSheets  totalViews
0  59e52591265adce80          393        3640
1  59e6763a265adce80          394        3642
```

Comment: @AlbertoTono yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your response to Wen-Ben's comment that this came from a JSON. Pandas has a [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) function that allows you to create a data frame straight from a JSON file. Based on the string you had in the column, I would try `pd.read_json('file.json', orient='index')`. Per the documentation:

> orient: string
>
> > Indication of expected JSON string format. Compatible JSON strings can be produced by to_json() with a corresponding orient value. The set of possible orients is:
> >
> > > 'index' : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}

Comment: Thanks a lot @tjeffkessler, unfortunately the JSON file was a bit more complex. I also have Multiple JSON root elements and the message "Expected object or value" in the main JSON file. not sure how I can divide these objects I will post another question about this problem soon.